# In what podcast and at what mark did Joel comment on pre-pacakaged social interaction apps like Facebook, Twitter, MySpace, etc.?

Tags: discussion, podcast, twitter, facebook

In a recent Stack Overflow podcast, fifty or sixty something, Joel Spolsky commented on social network sites replacing real social groups and interactions that would consist of your friends at the bar or pub.

I cannot google the transcripts for the exact quote and was hoping someone remembers the podcast and the point in the show where the statement was made.

Comment: Everyun git yer transcript wiki fu on!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.fogbugz.com/

Answer (score 3):

They did talk about those sites, but no statement was made regarding social network sites replacing real social groups and interactions.

There is a listener question in [episode 52](http://cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode52-2009.05.05.mp3), 38 min 08 secs, about employers doing background checks on social networking sites (mentions MySpace, Facebook and Twitter as examples). But the answer is all about controlling your identity on the Internet.

Comment: *behold your necromancy!*

Comment: @Jeff Atwood: indeed.